# Function being executed twice when it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, html

Im making a cookie clicker like game to practice Javascript. The point of the function addFarm(farmAdd) is to add a certain amount of farms when called. Using console.log, i have found that the setinterval executes twice every 1000ms instead of once every 1000ms leading to the banana count getting +30 added every second instead of +15. I imagine it is because the addFarm function is called twice in the code but the first time it is in an if statement that shouldnt be getting executed since the addFarm1 var is set to true and not false.

I am new to javascript (about a week) and cant figure out why it does this. Any help would be appreciated

```
function addFarm(farmAdd) { // this is the function
    farmCount = farmCount + farmAdd;
    farmAdd = 0;
    farmIncrement = farmCount * 5;

    farmCountText.textContent = farmCount + ' (+' + farmIncrement + ')';    

    setInterval(function() { // this part is executed twice every 1000ms
        bananaCount = bananaCount + farmIncrement;
        bananaCountText.textContent = bananaCount;
        console.log(farmIncrement);
    }, 1000);
}

function bananaClick() {
    bananaCount += 1;

    if (bananaCount > 10000) {
        bananaClicked.textContent = 'Golden Banana Bunch (+15)';
        banana.src = 'images/banana6.png';
        countByTwo(3);

        if (!addFarm1) {
            addFarm(1);
            addFarm1 = true;
        }
    }

    if (bananaCount > 15000) {
        bananaClicked.textContent = 'Mario Banana (+23)';
        banana.src = 'images/banana7.png';
        countByTwo(4);

        if (!addFarm2) {
            addFarm(2);
            addFarm2 = true;
        }
    }

    bananaCountText.textContent = bananaCount;
}
```

there is more code but i havent added it so i can make the post shorter but if you need more context then ask please :)

Comment: well, if bananaCount > 15000, then both conditions are true - change the order, and use else if .... `if (bananaCount > 15000) { .... } else if (bananaCount > 10000) { ... }` - changing the order of the tests is required for obvious reasons

Comment: @Bravo i did what you said (reversed order and also changed it to else if) yet the function still executes twice, they are just slightly delayed so that it executes twice within 200ms or so.

Comment: are you saying `bananaClick` runs twice or `addFarm` runs twice?

Comment: the setInterval inside of addFarm runs twice. im not sure if the entire addfarm function runs twice but the setinterval function definitely runs twice

Comment: well, how many times is `bananaClick` executed?

Comment: its executed everytime that i click a html element (img). it isnt executed multiple times each click because i get the amount of bananas i am supposed to get on click

Answer (score 0):

I imagine when you binded the click event for bananaClick you may be doing it twice.

For instance:

```
document.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('c'), )
document.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('c'), )
```

Will print c twice everytime it's clicked.

If there will only be one timer going at a time, you can clear it each time
it's called.

```
let timer;

let a = () => {
   
   clearInterval(timer)
   timer = setInterval(  ()=> {
   console.log('bananas')
  
  }, 2000)
}

a()
a()
a()      // only one timer will be active
```